# Short story where a moved book in a library changes time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

Caution, this one is a little complicated...

My girlfriend is searching for a book her father read long time ago. Here are the snippets I'm aware of:

- The story was in a book containing multiple short stories
- The book is maybe from around the 70's
- The story has time travel or alternative timelines as topic

Here is what I know from the story:

- When a book's position in a library is changed it causes real events to change.
- Due to this change, a civilization may rise or be destroyed
- This change is supervised from some sort of time-watcher, institution or similar

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds a little bit like "End of Eternity" by Isaac Asimov from 1955. While not exactly a collection of short stories, it does have a series of chapters describing the recruitment and training of the protagonist as an "Eternal". A description can be found at:

[End of Eternity](http://www.npr.org/2011/07/14/134978930/isaac-asimov-time-travel-and-the-end-of-eternity)

"The complicated plot of the book goes something like this: Our hero, Andrew Harlan, is an Eternal — a scientist operating from a tract of cosmic real estate known as Eternity. Eternity is a sort of bubble that exists outside of time and space. Or, in the metaphorical approach of the book, it's like an extratemporal elevator shaft running parallel to forward-moving Time.

Eternals can move up and down this shaft — "upwhen" and "downwhen" — getting off at stations in any century to enact Reality Changes. These changes alter the flow of human events toward outcomes producing "the maximum good for the maximum number.""

**The book to which are referring sounds like it might be the "Temporal Handbook"** which the Eternals use in monitoring/changing timelines. Below is a description, along with an excerpt description of the book.

Below that excerpt is a section in the book in which it describes **a "Minimal Necessary Change" or MNC in which the course of an entire civilization is changed by moving a container from one shelf to another.**

> He paused again at the infinitely thin curtain of non-Space and
>   nonTime which separated him from Eternity in one way and from
>   ordinary Time in another.
>   This would be a completely new section of Eternity for him. He
>   knew about it in a rough way, of course, having checked upon it in the
>   *Temporal Handbook*. Still, there was no substitute for actual
>   appearance and he steeled himself for the initial shock of adjustment.
>   He adjusted the controls, a simple matter in passing into
>   Eternity (and a very complicated one in passing into Time, a type of
>   passage which was correspondingly less frequent). He stepped
>   through the curtain and found himself squinting at the brilliance.
>   Automatically he threw up his hand to shield his eyes.
>   Only one man faced him. At first Harlan could see him only
>   blurrily.
>   The man said, "I am Sociologist Kantor Voy. I imagine you are
>   Technician Harlan."
>   Harlan nodded and said, "Father Time! Isn't this sort of
>   ornamentation adjustable?"
>   Voy looked about and said tolerantly, "You mean the molecular
>   films?"
>   "I certainly do," said Harlan. The *Handbook* had mentioned
>   them, but had said nothing of *such* an insane riot of light
>   reflection.

====

> The Sociologist winced at the initials as Harlan knew he would.
>   M.N.C.--Minitnum Necessary Change. There the Technician was
>   master. A Sociologist might consider himself above criticism by lesser
>   beings in anything involving the mathematical analysis of the infinite
>   possible Realities in Time, but in matters of M.N.C. the Technician
>   stood supreme.
>   Mechanical computing would not do. The largest Computaplex
>   ever built, manned by the cleverest and most experienced Senior
>   Computer ever born, could do no better than to indicate the ranges in
>   which the M.N.C. might be found. It was then the Technician, glancing
>   over the data, who decided on an exact point within that range. A
>   good Technician was rarely wrong. A top Technician was never
>   wrong.
>   Harlan was never wrong.
>   "Now the M.N.C. recommended," said Harlan (he spoke coolly,
>   evenly, pronouncing the Standard Intertemporal Language in precise
>   syllables), "by your Section involves induction of an accident in space
>   and the immediate death by fairly horrible means of a dozen or more
>   men."
>   "Unavoidable," said Voy, shrugging.
>   **"On the other hand," said Harlan, "I suggest that the M.N.C. can
>   be reduced to the mere displacement of a container from one shelf to
>   another. Here!"**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I will check if this is the right book. Or if not, if I can get some more details.

Comment: Hi, again. I read the book and find it quite interesting. But I'm not convinced that this is the book. However, I forwarded the book. Still thanks.

Comment: So, the original recipient is not 100% convinced but think that's the book. So Thanks for the input.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Thank you for selecting as answer.